# Я первый раз видел артиста, который играл в этом фильме

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я первый раз видел артиста, который играл в этом фильме.
почему нужно использовать который, а не которого? Получается тут И.п.? кто играл?

Answer (score 1):

**fob**, относительное местоимение «который» стоит в И. п. потому, что, помимо своей функции *союзного слова*, связывающего в сложноподчинённом предложении его придаточную часть с главной, оно здесь является *подлежащим* придаточного предложения. А подлежащему положено стоять именно в И. п.

> Сою́зные слова́ — местоименные слова (собственно местоимения и местоименные наречия), выполняющие функцию средства связи частей сложноподчинённого предложения. Одновременно с этим союзные слова выполняют и роль того или иного члена предложения, то есть совмещают функции знаменательного и служебного слова...
>
> https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0